# Installing jboss jsf 3.3 tools (no others) for Eclipse 3.7 breaks my block comment shortcut ctrl+shift+L in the jsf 2 xhtml file

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jboss

It worked before I installed the JBoss tools, but if I uninstall the jboss tools it's still broke.  It's driving me crazy.

In addition to that, Eclipse doesn't throw warning or error messages when I enter undefined tags in my xhtml files.  It flags undefined html tags like , but it's ok with .  This is not Jboss related.

Comment: block comment ? you mean mark several line and then press ctrl + shift + c ?

Comment: yes, but the shortcut is ctrl+shift+L

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this : `Windows->Preferences->General->Keys` , and change the "`Ctrl + Shift + C`" for toggle comments into "`Ctrl + Shift + L`" ? (for an easier finding of the shortcut you can order the table of shortcuts by Bindings Column...)